# Python: compare lists.Make a function that indicates if the word def is in quotation marks

Tags: python, list, function, comparison

> Make a function that indicates if each word *def* in the following sentence is in quotation marks.
>
> ```
> " hello world def  " def "  hi def"
> ```

First what I did is make a list with the positions of the word *def* and a list with the positions of the quotation marks.

```
list_def=[14,21,31]
list_quotes=[0,19,25,34]
```

My idea is make a function that compare if the position of the word def is betwen in a pair of quotation marks positions. I tried it but I am having some problems. Can you help me with that please?

```
for x in list_def:
    for y in list_quotes:
        if y<x:
            min = y
        elif i>x:
            max = y
    if min<x<max:
        print("Under quototation marks")
    else:
        print("Not under quotation marks")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using indices, use `re`:

```
import re
s = ' hello world def  " def "  hi def'
val = bool(re.findall('(?<="\s)def(?=\s")', s))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Edit: without modules:

```
s = ' hello world def  " def "  hi def'
def_occurs = [i for i, a in enumerate(s.split()) if a == 'def']
new_s = s.split()
occurs = {i:False if i in [0, len(new_s)-1] else (new_s[i-1] == '"' and new_s[i+1] == '"') for i in def_occurs}
```

Output:

```
{2: False, 4: True, 7: False}
```

Comment: But is there another way to do it  without modules?

Comment: thanks for your answer. In the sentence there are 3 def, so if I want to know if each def  is under quotations marks or not , how can I make it?

Comment: @David Please see my recent edit. The code now creates a dictionary which displays the index of each `def` and whether or not it is surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you check this new question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561409/python-indicate-if-a-word-is-in-quotation-marks-or-not

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few ways of doing that.
You could use Regular expressions, for example:

```
import re
def is_word_between_quotation_marks(word, sentence):
   match = re.search('"\\s*{}\\s*"'.format(word), sentence)
   return match is not None
```

Or you could also strip all the spaces in the string and check if "def" is inside the string:

```
def is_word_between_quotation_marks(word, sentence):
    return '"{}"'.format(word) in sentence.replace(' ', '')
```

Both are called this way:

```
is_word_between_quotation_marks('def', '" hello world def  " def "  hi def"')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in the sentence there are 3 def, so if I want to know if each def  is under quotations marks or not , how can I make it?